# std::pair<U,V> alignment control

Tags: c++, memory-alignment, std-pair

I noticed one unpleasant thing that happens with std::pair when tried to save it into binary file: std::pair is aligned to a word. It might be useful in terms of processor efficiency, but requires more storage space, so I want to switch align mode to 1-byte for std::pair. My compiler is MS VC++ 2012.

```
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    struct S_a { double a; size_t b; };

#pragma pack(1)
    struct S_wa { double a; size_t b; };

    std::cout << sizeof( size_t ) << '\n';                          // 4
    std::cout << sizeof( double ) << '\n';                          // 8
    std::cout << sizeof( std::pair< size_t, size_t > ) << '\n';     // 8
    std::cout << sizeof( std::pair< double, size_t > ) << '\n';     // 16 - bad
    std::cout << sizeof( S_wa ) << '\n';                            // 12 - good
    std::cout << sizeof( S_a ) << '\n';                             // 16
    std::cout << sizeof( std::pair< double, double > ) << '\n';     // 16
}
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
#pragma pack(1)
    typedef std::pair< double, size_t > Q;

    std::cout << sizeof( Q ) << '\n';                               // 16
```

Comment: Under project properties, try changing the *C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Struct Member Alignment* option (`/Zp1`)

Comment: Instead of screwing over your runtime, wouldn't it be better just to write special functions that handle reading and writing pair objects compactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, the `pack` pragma won't work for you in this situation. You could

```
#define _CRT_PACKING 1
#include <utility>
```

This can cause ALL SORTS of problems. One of which is that certain APIs, especially low-level ones, expect data to be aligned in a certain way. Not all of them are smart enough to deal with the situation where it's not; which could lead to unceremonious crashing.

If you really want the object to be serialised like this, handle the serialisation of `std::pair<U,V>` yourself (example only):

```
template<typename U, typename V>
void paircpy(char *dest, const std::pair<U, V> &pair) {
    memcpy(buffer, &pair.first, sizeof(U));
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(U), &pair.second, sizeof(V));
}
```

You would want to handle the special case for data types that don't `memcpy` well.

What you really should do, for any serious project, is serialise objects in a portable way so that they're retrievable and elegantly handle things like floating point, different encodings for signed data types, *pointers*, arrays, STL containers and anything else where a simple dump of the object's memory is not possible or is insufficient.

Read the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialize-overview.html) and develop your own serialisation modules which are more than just dumping the in-memory representation of the object to file.

Alternatively, you can use a pre-packaged portable solution for serialising data types such as

- [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization)
- Google's [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- The [XDR](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xdr) library
- JSON or XML

Comment: Okay. I have a class ArrayFile<T> that handles a std::vector, attached to file on disk and already do some marshalling. I think, it would be right to specialize explicitly ArrayFile to T=std::pair<U,V> and reduce the alighnment there, without changing a memory allocation. ok?

Comment: `#pragma pack` before `#include <utility>` won't do anything, because `<utility>` defines its own packing using the `_CRT_PACKING` macro.

Comment: @AlexanderMihailov Actually, it would be better to marshal objects in a portable way.

Answer (score 5):

A `std::pair` basically reduces down to:

```
class xxx
{
   T1 _t1;
   T2 _t2;
};
```

The alignment of the two members is defined by the alignment in force **when the template itself is defined**, not just when it's used to instantiate an instance.

The Microsoft implementation of the STL uses the symbol `_CRT_PACKING` to define the packing used for all STL components. By default the packing is set to 8. If you define this symbol yourself before including the header that defines `std::pair` (`<utility>`) you can theoretically override the packing and set your own.

Be aware of potential problems you may encounter calling libraries or other code that assumes the standard packing.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, totally different 'solution' that may or may not be a good idea, but hey if it works who am I to stop you from knowing. It comes with all of the same caveats as the other answers, but allows you to pick and choose your poisons.

Do a partial specialization of `std::pair` for the types that you care about, using the pragma pack for that particular definition, ex. for `char` and `int`:

```
namespace std {
#pragma pack( /* ... whatever you want ... */ )
template<> struct pair<char,int> {
  char first;
  int second;
};
}
```

With the definition somewhere you can touch it, you can affect the packing. Again, this is only good if you're willing to do it for all relevant types, and keep in mind the caveats mentioned by the other posters.

<sup>and there's the small chance that the library you're using is crazy and decided to put more stuff in `pair` that the rest of the lib depends on, but you probably don't need to worry about it</sup>